# Yocto Build Maxium PARALLEL_MAKE, BB_NUMBER_THREADS

Tags: yocto

I recently tried to start the yocto build task with leaving `PARALLEL_MAKE` and `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` blank, e.g. commented out and starting the Build on a Host with 48 or 64 vCPU's. The build was failing. With 32 vCPU's it still works. Yocto is still old Krogoth and cannot be updated currently. Does anybody knows if there is a limitation going further than 32 vCPU's? Is this just for older Yocto versions or generally an Issue?

Update: The error is related to a custom recipe for compiling a rnnoise-plugin:

`../rnnoise-plugin/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.1449627`

```
rnnoise-plugin/1.0-r0/asound-pcm-plugin-rnnoise.c:16:28: fatal error: alsa/asoundlib.h: No such file or directory
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
                            ^
```

As mentioned above, i only get this error when compiling on a 48 or 64 vCPU Host with `PARALLEL_MAKE` and `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` left blank. If i set `PARALLEL_MAKE="-j 32"` and `BB_NUMBER_THREADS="32"` it compiles without any error.

Comment: Define "build was failing".

Comment: @tinu73 what was the exact error you got? Can you please update your question with details of the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you run into race conditions when compiling with that many threads.

The yocto reference recommends setting `PARELLEL_MAKE` so `make` uses a maximum of 20 threads when using more than one physical CPU. If your system only has a single CPU this might be a virtualization problem.

> For single socket systems (i.e. one CPU), you should not have to override this variable to gain optimal parallelism during builds. However, if you have very large systems that employ multiple physical CPUs, you might want to make sure the PARALLEL_MAKE variable is not set higher than "-j 20".

[Yocto Project - PARALLEL_MAKE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-PARALLEL_MAKE)

For increased building speed you can try to fix this dependency issue by patching the appropriate Makefile ([Debugging Parallel Make Races](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#debugging-parallel-make-races))

**Edit**:

It is possible to set `PARALLEL_MAKE` for a particular package when overwriting in its recipe which allows to compile one particular package with `make -j 2` e.g. while other packages use maximum parallelism.

So it might be a suitable workaround to set `PARALLEL_MAKE` to a lower value in the recipe of the package where the dependency issue occurs.

But keep in mind that the yocto reference also recommends to limit `BB_NUMBER_THREADS` (no package-specific parameter) to `20` on large systems with multiple CPU's which might be the case when using hardware virtualization.

Comment: Is it possible to limit parallel processing just for once recipe, e.g. in one .bb file? The .bb where the compile error occurs?

Comment: You can overwrite `PARALLEL_MAKE` in your recipe. As I understand this would then only affect the `do_compile` task of this recipe and might be a suitable workaround to not slow down the whole build process. But I can't say for sure if that's the case - give it a try and set it only in your recipe with a low value

Comment: One alternative approach to overcome this problem is to change the bb file from `do_compile` to `do_install` and refer to the precompiled library in the files folder. What i don't know is, whether this corresponds to the basic ideas and concepts of Yocto.